# Display logo in CSS menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to place a logo in my navigation menu, like this http://prntscr.com/8rwb4i. I tried a lot of pieces of code, but I can't get it to work. Code can be found in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/askoc4qh/

```css
body {
 width:960px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin:5px auto; 
 padding:0 auto;
 
 }

ul {
 height:60px;
    width:100%px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0; 
    list-style-type:none;
 
 }

li {
 float:left;
 width:240px;
 }

ul a {
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:19px;
 display:block;
 
 }
 
ul li a {
 display:block;
 padding:20px 45px;
 line-height:1.0em;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition:500ms ease;
}
ul li ul {
 visibility: hidden;
}
 

ul a:hover {
 
 color:yellow; 
 background-color:black; 
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
 <ul>
 <li><a href = 'index.html'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'media.html'>Media Design</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'innovatie.html'>Innovatieroutes</a>
 <li><a href = 'info.html'>Opleiding</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'info.html'>Fontys</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'info.html'>Toekomst</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that your logo perfectly fit to `<li>`, than try this one:

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href = 'index.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href = 'media.html'>Media Design</a></li>
    <li><a href = 'innovatie.html'>Innovatieroutes</a>
    <li><a href = 'info.html'>Opleiding</a></li>
    <li><a href = 'info.html'>Fontys</a></li>
    <li><a href = 'info.html'>Toekomst</a></li>
    <li><a href = 'contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
    <li><img src="https://shopsocially.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/GreyBackground-48.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  width:960px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin:5px auto; 
  padding:0 auto;
}

ul {
  height:60px;
  width:100%px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0; 
  list-style-type:none;
}

li {
  float:left;
  width:240px;
  height: 59px;
  overflow: hidden; /*cuts the img*/
}

ul a {
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:19px;
  display:block;
}

ul li a {
  display:block;
  padding:20px 45px;
  line-height:1.0em;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition:500ms ease;
}

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul a:hover {    
  color:yellow; 
  background-color:black; 
}

img{
  width:100%;
}
```

There is another way to improve your problem, you can delete  `overflow: hidden;` and set:

```
img{
  width: 100%;
  /*new line*/
  height: 100%; /*Doesn't cut your img*/
}
```

You can also look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/aqeeLvsd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can Add the logo in the last `<li>` like

```
<li><a href = 'info.html'>Toekomst</a></li>
<li><a href = 'contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
<li><a><img src="yourlogo.png"></a> </li>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/askoc4qh/1/)